# Recyclerview inside nested fragment is not showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a fragment which contain a viewpager . The viewpager itself contain fragments which contain recyclerview and textview . The problem is that textview is showing in all 5 tabs but recyclerview only shows at 2-3 tabs(randomly) .

[image: 1.jpg]

[image: 2.jpg]

Here is my code

Parent Fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
toolbar = (Toolbar) fragmentActivity.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
tabLayout = (TabLayout) fragmentActivity.findViewById(R.id.my_tablayout);
mCollapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)    fragmentActivity.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout);
viewPager = (ViewPager) fragmentActivity.findViewById(R.id.my_pager);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)    getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
          adapter = new GameListPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),getContext());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

ViewPager Adapter

```
public class GameListPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
private Context context;
private String pageTitle[] = {"Replaying", "Planning", "dropped", "playing","completed"};

public GameListPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){

        case 0 :
            return GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.REPLAYING);
        case 1 :
            return GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.PLANNING);
        case 2 :
            return GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.DROPPED);
        case 3 :
            return GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.PLAYING);
        case 4:
            return GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.COMPLETED);

        default:
            return GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(position);

    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return pageTitle[position];
}


}
```

Child Fragment containing textview and recyclerveiw

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Toaster.make(getContext(),"onActivity");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    realmResult =  realm.where(GameListDatabase.class).findAll();
    Toaster.make(getContext(),realmResult.size()+"");
    GameListAdapter adapter = new GameListAdapter(getContext(),realmResult,true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Comment: Why you used return instead of break in switch statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't create new items in your `getItem(position)` method of your adapter. Instead create a `List`  of fragments and populate it in your Constructor so that you don't create new instances everytime.

```
public class GameListPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private String pageTitle[] = {"Replaying", "Planning", "dropped", "playing", "completed"};
    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

    public GameListPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
        fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.REPLAYING));
        fragments.add(GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.PLANNING));
        fragments.add(GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.DROPPED));
        fragments.add(GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.PLAYING));
        fragments.add(GamesListPagerFragment.newInstance(GiantBomb.COMPLETED));
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return pageTitle[position];
    }
}
```

Also move your following code:

```
Toaster.make(getContext(),"onActivity");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    realmResult =  realm.where(GameListDatabase.class).findAll();
    Toaster.make(getContext(),realmResult.size()+"");
    GameListAdapter adapter = new GameListAdapter(getContext(),realmResult,true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

from your `onActivityCreated` to your `onCreateView` method of your child fragment.
If you don't have many child fragments then you can set your `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit`to the number of fragments you have, in this case 5.

Comment: thankyou so much man , you are life saver :) . On moving the above code from onActivityCreated to onCreateView it worked . Any reason for this ?

Comment: Yes, `onActivityCreated` is called after the activity is created. It is okay to use the code in there if your fragments are created in `onCreate` of the activity. But in your case, you created new instances of fragments every time you changed the page (since in your `getItem` method you created new instances). So the activity was created before the fragments were, thus leading to `onActivityCreated` not being called in some of your fragments. Now `onCreateView` is always called, so it will populate the recyclerview.

Answer (score 2):

Fragments have a tendency to be destroyed immediately when they are not in view. Here is what you can try:

**1.** Try using `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, or better yet, directly extend `PagerAdapter`.

**2.** Add `setRetainInstance(true)` in the `onCreate()` of your child fragments.

**3.** Try setting `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5)`.

Some combination of the above should work. Try it.

Comment: thanks for the answer . Unfortunately 2) doesn't work for nested fragment . I triend 3) and 1) and still the problem remain . Will try directly by extending PageAdapter now .